# How can I find the IP of Active Directory Domain Controller(s) from Unix?

Tags: java, active-directory

I can get the nameserver via NSLOOKUP on a Windows machine and get an AD DC via a WMI VBS script, but I can't use the VBS script from a Unix server ( which can ping the nameserver). 
I'd like to use Java to obtain all the Active Directory domain controllers from a Unix box.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can query the DNS Server, can't you perform a query for its service records to discover computers that can act as Domain Controllers?

That's how Windows Workstations find their candidate Domain Controllers.

Comment: How to ask DNS to discover controllers ?

Comment: I found it later - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/247811 with `dig` command in Unix you can do `dig SRV _ldap._tcp.[DnsDomainName]`, where DnsDomainName is your domain...

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to look into java.net package which contains various classes like INetAddress, URLConnection and various socket classes that you might find useful.

Comment: I'm aware of these classes...
Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you can connect to it like standard LDAP. You can use the OpenLDAP Library:

http://www.openldap.org/jldap/

Comment: 'Tis the basis of my question.